# XeLateX misplaces figures over text

Tags: graphics, xetex

When I do

```
Latex > DVItoPS > PStoPDF
```

figures appear correctly. But when I use XeLaTex, it misplaces some figures over text. I draw the frame of eps files by

```
\frame{\includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth]{eps/my_fig.eps}}
```

and the frame appears in the correct position, but the figure is totally shifted down and left.

When I open eps files with eps viewer it looks correct, and I also used epstool to correct boundary boxes.

What could be the problem?

I tried an minimum working example, and it works.

But here is the problematic code, that causes all problems. When I delete that the figures appear correctly.

```
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
  \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
  % declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
   \graphicspath{{../pdf/}{../jpeg/}{../eps/}{eps/}}
  % and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
  % every instance of \includegraphics
   \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png, .eps}
\else
  % or other class option (dvipsone, dvipdf, if not using dvips). graphicx
  % will default to the driver specified in the system graphics.cfg if no
  % driver is specified.
   \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
  % declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
   \graphicspath{{../eps/}{eps/}{data/}}
  % and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
  % every instance of \includegraphics
  \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
\fi
```

**UPDATE: pdflatex also produces figures correctly.**

Comment: The code assumes only `pdftex` or `dvi + dvips`.
XeTeX requires `xetex.def`. Usually, except for
a few cases, a suitable driver is taken automatically by calling
graphicx package without a driver option.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto yes I changed pdftex to xetex above, still the same problem.

Comment: The code that was suggested to you is wrong: the `pdftex` or `dvips` options should never be passed to `graphicx`. Just remove that code and simply add `\usepackage{graphicx}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why the IEEE templates continue to suggest adding that code, which is wrong to begin with.

Just replace that code by

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

You may want to add a `\graphicspath` declaration, but it's optional. Don't add `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions` command.